# Project "xxx" has one or more liens on it to prevent accidental deletion. To delete the project, remove the liens first then try again

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I try to delete the GCP project, but got below information:

[image]

When I click the **Remove lien** link, the browser redirects me to Dialogflow web UI. But give me an error:

> com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project 'slate-bf0ec'.

I had deleted all Dialogflow agents before. I still can't delete the GCP project. There is nothing to delete on Dialogflow web UI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did it deleting the liens using the console.

1. Go to Google Cloud Shell & Set to your project.

`gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`

2. List the project liens

`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`

3. Delete by name

`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]`

4. Delete the project

Comment: Works perfectly. Otherwise, even after deleting, the changes will take 24-48 hours to be implemented.

Comment: for additional, if you don't have gcloud sdk in your machine,, you can try it direcly with cloudshell on google cloud console in your browser :)

Answer (score 2):

A "lien" is a protection against deletion.

They can be added manually or automatically - e.g. adding a Dialogflow agent to a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project automatically adds a lien to the project.

However, removing a Dialogflow agent does not automatically removed the lien - and the only way to get rid of it is by using the gcloud CLI.

**Prerequisites**

1. Setup the gcloud CLI (see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstarts)
2. Install the alpha component for gcloud

   `gcloud components install alpha`

   **NB:** Be aware that alpha commands can change without notice. See (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha)

**List existing liens on a GCP project**

`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list --project [PROJECT_ID]`

**Delete existing liens**

`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

**Delete project**

`gcloud projects delete [PROJECT_ID]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an agent [1] and specify `slate-bf0ec` as Google project then delete it using the Dialogflow console (the delete agent operation found in the General tab of its settings).

[1] https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/#/newAgent